# How to control Y-axis units using sm.density.compare()

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have used sm.density.compare to plot 3 density functions for data with values between -90 and +10.  The Y axis is labeled "density" and has the range 0 - 1.0 as for proportions or probability.

I then plot 4 density functions for data with values between 0 and 1.0.  I get a useful plot and the Y axis still reads "density" but the values are apparently counts and range between 0 and 12 or so.

The function sm.options does not seem to offer control of which you get.  I'd like both to be probability or proportions.

I'm new to R but have a substantial history with other software.